# Save Multi image in database MVC5

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database

I need to save Multi-image in a database now the folwing code save only one image

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Create(wood_project wood_project, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.wood_project.Add(wood_project);

            if (file != null)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                wood_project.Img = ImageName;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(wood_project);
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        Image 
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  multiple /> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

[I create relationship  betwen the tabels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCFnL.png) 
Plese help me with code  ?

Comment: You need to change the parameter to `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file` (and loop through each file). But then your `Img` property makes no sense, and you would need a 2nd database table to store each file name with a FK relationship to the `wood_project` table

Answer (score 0):

To store multiple images that relate to a single entity, you would need a relational schema.

Relate your "Wood_Project" table to an images table, where each row in the images table relates back to a wood_project_Id. Then you can store the files directly in the database or just store the filename and have all files stored on a directory.

EDIT: Here is some C# psuedocode with the general idea, add your wood_project row to the database, then loop through each image and add it to your images table with the original wood_project_Id as a foreign key:

```
            db.wood_project.Add(wood_project);
            db.SaveChanges();


            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                //loop through files and add them to new table
                foreach(var file in files)
                {
                    db.MyImagesTable.Add(MyImagesTableObject()
                        {
                            wood_project_Id = wood_project.Id,
                            ImgData = file.data
                        });

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

Hope this idea helps.

Comment: I create the relationship between the tables Plese help me with the code ?

Comment: @Ms.Fatima I have updated my answer with some code that should help you on your way.

Comment: the code was not meant to be a direct copy and paste into your solution, and only a guide to how you can achieve your goal.

Comment: yes, of course, I changed the code according to the input I have but an error message appeared 
A local or parameter named 'file' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @Ms.Fatima yes that is probably because the pseudocode I wrote is using file as the foreach loop alias as well as the name for the parameter of your method. Change the parameter of your method to be a list of files and name it something else like "files". Like I said earlier, the code is just a guide for the logic and will not work copy and pasted into your solution.